# Resolving a Promise Chain Using Node, Mysql, and TypeScript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I am working in node and typescript.  I have a controller and a repository.  I can log the data out all over the place EXCEPT at the return from the repo.  Of course, the controller gets back nothing.  Here are the pastebins:

- [package.json](https://gist.github.com/6f4aeeafe3a474835089c70fae1842d2)
- [users_controller.ts](https://gist.github.com/af8ce840ccfad8a35dd6c2d57f53f2be)
- [users_repository.ts](https://gist.github.com/5dbdcdbb96cd12ad1a96a28b8fa079c9)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to use Promises. The getUsers() method is called and returns before the Promise has a chance to resolve. The quickest way to fix it is to return the Promise from the getUsers() method or use async/await. Essentially, all of the logic that you have to update the userModels value happens after the function has already returned an empty array.